# How to have my loop range be changing based on conditions

Tags: vba, excel, loops

i don't know if my problem description is accurate, but basically i have this: [image]

Since I'm working with positions here, each position comes in a pair. I want to loop through the whole list down and calculate the difference in value in each position pair (so i want to find the loss or the gain), and return it to another cell. here the difference between the 1st position pair is 14688, the following is another position. I've done a short code here to try to get the logic right, but it definitely isn't. any help here guys? Thanks a lot in advance. If im being vague with my question I will amend it.

The first position is in row 63.

```
Sub hello()

Dim sum As Long
Dim i As Long

For i = 63 To 100
    sum = range("T63").Value + range("T" & i)

    Do While sum <> 0
        If range("Y" & i) > 0 Then

'add result here

        End if
    Loop
Next
```

End Sub

Comment: (1) For every repeat of your loop, you add `range("T63").Value` to `sum`. My guess is that you should (a) intialise `sum` to `range("T63").Value`, (b) loop from 64 and (c) add interesting values to `sum` so `sum = sum + range("T" & i)`. (2) Your description says you are looking for the second position of a pair but does not say how you recognise the second of a pair. (3) I would start by writing a description of how you would do this without the help of a macro. How do you know to start at row 63? What is it about row 63 that allows you to know that row X is its pair?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since your data "structure" has single not empty cells delimited by empty cells, then you could exploit the [`Areas`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196243.aspx) property and the [`SpecialCells()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157.aspx) method of `Range` object, like follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim iPair As Long
    Dim pairDiff As Double

    With Worksheets("lossgain") '<-- change "losspair" to your actual worksheet name
        With .Range("T63", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "T").End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers) '<--| loop through column "T" cells containing numbers from row 63 down to last not empty one
            iPair = 1 '<--| initialize "pair" counter
            Do While iPair < .Areas.Count '<--| loop through "pairs"
                pairDiff = .Areas(iPair + 1).Offset(, 1) - .Areas(iPair).Offset(, 1) '<--| calculate the "pair" difference from corresponding column "U" values
                .Areas(iPair + 1).Offset(, IIf(pairDiff < 0, 2, 3)) = pairDiff '<--| write "pair" difference in corresponding column "V" (if loss) or "W" (if gain)
                iPair = iPair + 2 '<--| update "pair" counter by adding two not to mix "pairs"
            Loop
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

follow comments and step through the code to see what's happening

Comment: Hi @user3598756, thanks for you answer! your code was successful in putting the difference in a corresponding row of another column at the end of the position pair, but unfortunately i don't get the correct difference. your code gives me a difference of -1897812, and the subsequent differences are incorrect to. how should i solve this?

Comment: Wait, my mistake. I didn't understand your code at first but now I do, and i figured it out and have amended it. Thanks so much :) This worked perfectly.

Comment: Hi @user3598756, i tried your code on a sheet with 6000 values and it only calculates the first few pairs, and then gives the error "type mismatch" at line pairDiff = .Areas(iPair + 1).Offset(, 1) + .Areas(iPair).Offset(, 1). how do i correct this?

Comment: Step through code and see what values are in .Areas(iPair + 1).Offset(, 1)  and .Areas(iPair).Offset(, 1) when it errors out.

Comment: the .Areas(iPair + 1).Offset(, 1) is 12 and  .Areas(iPair).Offset(, 1) is 13. why is this happening though?

Comment: wouldn't say why. Try wrapping values in `CDbl()`: `pairDiff = CDbl(.Areas(iPair + 1).Offset(, 1)) - CDbl(.Areas(iPair).Offset(, 1))`

Comment: tried that and .value, still has the same error. :/ hmmm

Comment: 1) is your data "structure" as per your example? (i.e. _single_ cells delimited by blank ones) 2) are there any merged cells?

Comment: I realised there are some instances that my values are consecutive. I don't have any merged cells. Ive reordered them to the code's structure to make sure the code runs, but it still gives the same error. In any case, is there any way to make the code work if there are consecutive values?

Comment: I'm sure there is. But this is another issue from your _original_ question. Then make a new post with your new issue and be sure to detail it properly like "column "U" cells with numbers can be either consecutive or not, still a "pair" is formed by two consecutive numbers in column "B" and so on. Post it along your coding efforts and failures which are always a good starting point for everybody willing to help