# Looping to identify pairs in my data

Tags: vba, excel

i have this issue:

[image]

Since I'm working with positions here, each position comes in a pair. I want to loop through the whole list down and calculate the difference in value in each position pair (so i want to find the loss or the gain), and return it to another cell. here the difference between the 1st position pair is 14688, the following is another position pair. With the help from some awesome people here, I've made use of the  `Area`  property since the structure of my data is a non-empty cell delimited by empty cells. However, i need a code that takes into account data that has consecutive non-empty cells like below, and still pair them up.

The first position is in row 63.

```
Sub main()
    Dim iPair As Long
    Dim pairDiff As Variant


    pairDiff = 1

    With Worksheets("System 1") 
        With .range("T39", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "T").End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers) '<--| loop through column "T" cells containing numbers from row 63 down to last not empty one
            iPair = 1 '<--| initialize "pair" counter
            Do While iPair < .Areas.Count '<--| loop through "pairs"
                 pairDiff = .Areas(iPair + 1).Offset(, 1) + .Areas(iPair).Offset(, 1)
                .Areas(iPair + 1).Offset(, IIf(pairDiff < 0, 7, 8)) = pairDiff '<--| write "pair" difference in corresponding column "V" (if loss) or "W" (if gain)
                iPair = iPair + 2 '<--| update "pair" counter by adding two not to mix "pairs"
            Loop
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Any help? If u need me to be specific with my question i will edit it accordingly. thank you.

Comment: Did you try anything yet? I am asking this because the code you posted is the answer to one of your previous questions...

Comment: Could you expand on your example?  Perhaps by showing us what you would expect to see before and after the code has run?

Comment: @Rcaetano Hi, i don't know how to go about doing it as im new to VBA, so I only shifted the cells manually, apologies.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to have my loop range be changing based on conditions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40281678/how-to-have-my-loop-range-be-changing-based-on-conditions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Areas` are still helpful, only you have to loop through each `Area` cells also

Option Explicit

```
Sub main()
    Dim ielem As Long
    Dim pair1stValue As Double, pairDiff As Double
    Dim area As Range, cell As Range

    With Worksheets("lossgain") '<-- change "losspair" to your actual worksheet name
        With .Range("T63", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "T").End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers) '<--| loop through column "T" cells containing numbers from row 63 down to last not empty one
            For Each area In .Areas
                For Each cell In area.Cells
                    ielem = ielem + 1
                    If Int(ielem / 2) * 2 = ielem Then
                        pairDiff = cell.Offset(, 1) - pair1stValue  '<--| calculate the "pair" difference from corresponding column "U" values
                        cell.Offset(, IIf(pairDiff < 0, 2, 3)) = pairDiff '<--| write "pair" difference in corresponding column "V" (if loss) or "W" (if gain)
                    Else
                        pair1stValue = cell.Offset(, 1)
                    End If
                Next
            Next
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```